Copy custom field from SOOrder to ARInvoice
I'm trying to follow this example so that value is copied regardless of how invoice is created (from SO or from Shipment):
Acumatica - Overriding Business logic, access protected methods
But method signatures have changed and I'm not having much luck.  Here is what I have so far in my SOInvoiceEntry extension but I get an error: AR Transactions cannot be found in the system.
        public delegate void InvoiceOrderDelegate(InvoiceOrderArgs args);

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void InvoiceOrder(InvoiceOrderArgs args)
    {
        //Code before
        Base.InvoiceOrder(args);
        //Code after

        InvoiceCreated(Base.Document.Current, args);
    }

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void InvoiceCreated(ARInvoice invoice, InvoiceOrderArgs args)
    {
        // Base.InvoiceCreated(invoice, args);
        ARRegisterExt registerExt = PXCache<ARRegister>.GetExtension<ARRegisterExt>(invoice);
        SOOrderExt orderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(args.SOOrder);

        registerExt.UsrLumpSumReport = orderExt.UsrLumpSumReport;
    }

Got it. Just had to invoke method on the delegate.
        [PXOverride]
    public virtual void InvoiceOrder(InvoiceOrderArgs args, InvoiceOrderDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        //Code before
        baseMethod?.Invoke(args);
        //Code after

        InvoiceCreated(Base.Document.Current, args);
    }

